# convert pixel coordinates to map coordinates

Tags: matlab, matrix, maps, utm

I have an image `A` of dimension `p x q`. If I know the UTM coordinate of `A(1,1)` and `A(p,q)` and pixel size in meters.

How to convert the pixel coordinates to map coordinates in MATLAB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Xsize = (1:p)*PixelSizeInMeter+UTM_x_onA11;
Ysize = (1:q)*PixelSizeInMeter+UTM_y_onA11;
figure;
surface(Xsize,Ysize,A);
```

Now you can plot your map using `Xsize` and `Ysize`. Since UTM is a Cartesian grid, life's quite easy: get the correct number of elements, multiply with the grid size and add the lower corner's coordinates to shift the plot to the correct location.